# Split logging on rsyslogd

Tags: linux, logging, log-files, rsyslog, syslog

My goal is to send all logs to one source remote and still log local but then send all the AuditD logs to its own source on port 20002. But for some reason, my auditd logs are still ending up with my syslogs going to port 20000

/etc/rsyslog.conf:

```
cat /etc/rsyslog.conf
module(load="imuxsock") # provides support for local system logging
module(load="imklog")   # provides kernel logging support

$ActionFileDefaultTemplate RSYSLOG_TraditionalFileFormat
$FileOwner root
$FileGroup adm
$FileCreateMode 0640
$DirCreateMode 0755
$Umask 0022

$WorkDirectory /var/spool/rsyslog
$IncludeConfig /etc/rsyslog.d/*.conf

local7.* ~

auth,authpriv.*                 /var/log/auth.log
*.*;auth,authpriv.none          -/var/log/syslog
cron.*                         /var/log/cron.log
daemon.*                        -/var/log/daemon.log
kern.*                          -/var/log/kern.log
lpr.*                           -/var/log/lpr.log
mail.*                          -/var/log/mail.log
user.*                          -/var/log/user.log

mail.info                       -/var/log/mail.info
mail.warn                       -/var/log/mail.warn
mail.err                        /var/log/mail.err

*.=debug;\
        auth,authpriv.none;\
        mail.none               -/var/log/debug
*.=info;*.=notice;*.=warn;\
        auth,authpriv.none;\
        cron,daemon.none;\
        mail.none               -/var/log/messages

*.emerg                         :omusrmsg:*
```

/etc/rsyslog.d/rsyslog_d_all.conf:

```
*.*;!local7.* action(type="omfwd" target="10.10.1.23" port="20000" protocol="tcp")
```

rsyslog_d_auditd.conf:

```
$ModLoad imfile
local7.* action(type="omfwd" target="10.10.1.23" port="20002" protocol="tcp")
$InputFileName /var/log/audit/audit.log
$InputFileTag tag_audit_log:
$InputFileStateFile audit_log
$InputFileSeverity info
$InputFileFacility local6
$InputRunFileMonitor
```

Comment: and what is the business related question in here?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is crossposted: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/750331/split-logging-on-rsyslogd